# Google App Engine plugin on NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: google-app-engine, macos, netbeans-6.9

I followed the instructions on this site: [Getting Started With Google App Engine and NetBeans](http://rocky.developerblogs.com/tutorials/getting-started-google-app-engine-netbeans/).

When I try to add a Google App Engine server, I correctly point it to the .app file on my computer. But it still complains to "Provide a valid Google App Engine location". Why is this so? Which location does the plug-in want?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the sdk zip file from google, http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3.zip,
and then unzipped the file into a java sandbox subdirectory of my home directory.  I then pointed to the unzipped directory structure and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with netbeans, but it appears it wants a path to the App Engine SDK. This is a subfolder of the app, `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine`.

Comment: It appeared as a ZIP file, I unzipped it, but NetBeans still won't accept it :(

Comment: @Kit Run the launcher and it will unzip itself into the path I specified.

Comment: Just did that a few minutes ago, and I also tried adding random folders within the `GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app` directory tree. To no avail :(

Comment: @Kit Are you sure it's not just looking for a directory to put your app? Maybe it expects a directory containing an `app.yaml`?

Comment: I tried going through the `helloworld` tutorial, complete with an `app.yaml`. I pointed the plugin to the `helloworld` folder with the `app.yaml`. Nada still. :( I don't think it should be looking for an `app.yaml` either.